# Qlikview project will not disappear after delete files/folder

Tags: qlikview

Hi i have disabled and deleted tasks and also deleted files/folders "resrpt". But it still remains in the QMC. Is this normal?
[Screenshot of QMC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yPuD.png)

Answer (score 1):

This means that that model had some attributes like assigned doc licenses or a reload scheduled.

**solution**
recreate the directory structure and create an empty qvw with the same name.
once the qmc recognize it, go through the document settings in the qmc and reset anything that is set. if there are license - remove them, disable the reload option, etc...

now you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You will to readd back to the Server location, then unallocate the DocCals and UserCals in QMC assigned to it.
Once you've done this you can then remove the files after disabling any related tasks

We've had a similar issue where the files had actually been deleted, so if you've done this without a backup, just create a new QVD that has the same filename as those on the server - then the assigned licenses will get recognized on QMC